# selenium - submenu click not working

Tags: selenium

i am not able to click the submenu.. tried with different xpath/id .....

below is the html tags, Main Menu is Presentations(marked in red arrow) and submenus are under div.

can you please let me know how i can write xpath for this. i wanted to click hypothetical in the submenu.

here main menu tag is at the bottom of div(submenu).

also attached selenium code . please help me....

`<div id="presentations" class="ToolbarSubMenu" align="left"`parent="presentations_parent">
`<a id="hypothetical" class="ToolbarMenu"  href="">Hypothetical</a><br/>`

`</div> 
<a id="presentations_parent" class="ToolbarMenu" href="">Presentations</a>`

```
@Test
public void hypothetical() 
{

    WebElement ic =  driver.findElement(By.id("presentations"));
    Actions act = new Actions(driver);
//  act.moveToElement(ic).click().build().perform();
    //act.moveToElement(ic).doubleClick().build().perform();
act.moveToElement(ic).clickAndHold().release().build().perform();
//ic.click();
    //driver.switchTo().window(myWindowHandle);

//  driver.findElement(By.linkText("Hypothetical")).click();
// driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[2][@id='presentations']/a[1]")).click();

//Actions act = new Actions(driver);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

//  WebElement hyp=driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Hypothetical"));

WebElement hyp=driver.findElement(By.id("//div[@id='presentations']/a[1]"));
//act.moveToElement(hyp).click().build().perform();


hyp.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.id("presentations")).click();
WebElement hyp = driver.findElement(By.id("hypothetical"));
hyp.click();
```

Comment: i tried with By.id options but no success. Main menu is "Presentations" is out side the "div".

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
 //Click on main menu that will opens the sub Menu list
 WebElement ic =  driver.findElement(By.id("presentations"));

 ic.click();
```

If your requirement is to click on each individual sub menu item,then use below code:
click for **Hypothetical** is:

```
 ic.findElement(By.id("hypothetical")).click();
```

click for Profile is:

```
ic.findElement(By.id("profile")).click();

  (Or)
```

You can also get all subMenu items at a time, like this:

```
 //Get all the sub menu list.
 List<WebElement> list = ic.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
 for(int i=0;i < list.size; i++){
     WebElement subMenuElement = list.get(i);
     subMenuElement.click();
 }
```

Comment: Hi Saritha, I tried with your code.. still not submenu not clickable. im not understanding what i have to do here. Here submenu is under "div" its not normal menu...

Comment: can you post your URL..??

Comment: No, its not shareable URL. i can share the img for html

Comment: ok that is also fine. And also share the image of menu from browser, so that i can know is that drop down or  something else.

Comment: have you what i have sent yesterday.